# What are the steps involved to get the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm just a bit confused on the math process to get from the left equation to the right
$$\left(\frac{s}{6}\frac{1-s^6}{1-s}\right)^2 = \frac{s^2}{36} (s^5 + s^4 +s^3+s^2+s+1)^2 $$

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed a square on the right side?

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Well spotted, Good Sir! now it's corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modified statement is now correct.

$$\Bigg(\frac{s(1-s^6)}{6(1-s)}\Bigg)^2=\frac{s^2}{36}[s^5+s^4+s^3+s^2+s+1]^2$$

To understand the algebraic passages let's focus on

$$(1-s^6)=(1+s^3)\underbrace{(1-s^3)}_{(1-s)(1+s+s^2)}$$

... simplify and get the correct result

Comment: You're right I did get it wrong initially. It's now been updated with the correct version

Comment: @Jimmy :... and I edited my answer with the solution. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future